# Node and Angular cookie path

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, cookies, express

I'm working on a login/out functionality for my web application. When the user logged in my NodeJS(Express) server sets cookies variable called "user" on .mydomain.com with path '/'. Then I use AngularJS to access user cookies. It reads it fine from any page under my domain, but when I want to log the user out. I try deleting the cookies value, but it doesn't delete it on any other pages than the index page ('/').

I know there's something to do with the cookies path, but as far as I know it's ok to read/write cookies with path '/' form anywhere in the same domain. Is that not the case?

Setting the cookies, NodeJS

```
res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify(response.user), {
    expires: moment().add('d', 2).toDate(),
    path: '/',
    domain: '.mydomain.com'
});
```

Deleting the cookies from /myPage/page2, AngularJS

```
delete $cookies['user'];
```

Is there anyway this could work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I usually post to the server.

So, on the client side, I have something like:

```
$scope.logout = function() {
  $http.post('/logout').then(function(){
    $state.go('login');
  });
};
```

and on the server side:

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
  delete req.session.user
  req.session.regenerate(done);
  res.json(200, 'OK');
});
```